# Web service request in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in objective C. I have done app in j2me and android using below code. I m trying same to consume web service through objective C but not getting success. It will be great if anyone guide me.

Thanks.

```
  public static String RetriveData(String myStr) 
{

    String result1 = "-1";
    Object ob1 = new Object();

   ob1 =MyStr;

    SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject("http://abcd.com/", "MyMethod");


    rpc.addProperty("Mystr",  ob1.toString());

    try 
    {


         Object strdata = new HttpTransport("http://11.22.33.44/myService.asmx", "http://abcd.com/" + "MyMethod").call(rpc);
        result1 = strdata.toString().trim();

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
                  System.out.println("In catch block   :" +ex);   

    }


  return result1;

  }
```

I am trying same through objective C as below but getting error.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://11.22.33.44/MyService.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
//
//[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://abcd.com/MyMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
//[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest addValue:@"MyStr" forHTTPHeaderField:@"MyStr"];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];


}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

[nameInput resignFirstResponder];

}

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
    [webData setLength: 0];
 }
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[webData appendData:data];
}
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
[connection release];
[webData release];
 }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]             length:     
 [webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(theXML);
[theXML release];

if( xmlParser )
{
    [xmlParser release];
}

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate: self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
[xmlParser parse];

[connection release];
[webData release];
   }
```

Comment: I am getting below error "The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported."

Comment: This is an HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type response code.  Try uncommenting the "content-type" line, or adding one for "accept".

Comment: Can you isolate the problem? People aren't very inclined to look at a wall of code to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is to use ASIHttpRequest.  I consume web services (both .NET and PHP) with it and it seems much easier and straightforward to use in most cases.

Just include the ASIHttpRequest classes and the MBProgressHUD (If you want to use it)

Here is what I use to do it:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.labelText = @"Connecting to Server";

// Start request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain/MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];

// Now setup the Request
[request setPostValue:@"MyValue1" forKey:@"WebServiceArg1"];
[request setPostValue:@"MyValue2" forKey:@"WebServiceArg2"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Now use the delegate methods to check and consume the response from the web service:

```
#pragma mark - ASIHttpRequest Delegate Methods
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        // Do something with this, create an array or dictionary depending on how the return data is structured (this assumes you are using a JSON formatted return string btw
        }
        else {
            // Standard UIAlert Syntax
            UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                                    message:@"My Message"
                                    delegate:nil 
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [myAlert show];

        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error finishing request");
    }

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                            message:@"Unable to establish connection" 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

There are many ways to do it but this is what I would use.

Comment: Note that ASIHTTPRequest's development is discontinued http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D The article names alternatives. AFNetworking is great.

Comment: [LRResty](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRResty) is another alternative to ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Dang!  I didn't know that.  Will look into the others. - Thx.